# ArrayList iteration gives exception java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: "This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible."

Any idea why my set method gives this exception?

```
private ArrayList<Double> voltagesList = new ArrayList<Double>();
private ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();

public void setVoltage(String device, double voltage) { 
    for(String d: devicesList){
            if(d.equals(device)){
                voltagesList.set(devicesList.indexOf(device), voltage);
        }
            else{
                voltagesList.add(voltage);
                devicesList.add(device);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the iteration that's causing the exception.

Comment: you are adding while iterating which is a bug because I assume you only want to add if it is not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a pair of Lists you should be using a Map.

```
private final Map<String, Double> deviceVoltageMap = new HashMap<>();

public void setVoltage(String device, double voltage) { 
    deviceVoltageMap.put(device, voltage);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the tip. One more question- how would I go about adding the values in a Map?

Comment: @Ian `put` will insert or replace.

Comment: I mean in a separate function, I wish to add the values stored in the Map, after setting them.

Comment: @Ian Do you means you want multiple voltages for the same device? In that case use `MultiMap` or `Map<String, List<Double>>`

Answer (score 2):

Yes the reason you're getting this is `devicesList.add(device);`  You are adding to this list **as you're iterating it**.  You can't do that in a foreach loop on an `ArrayList` .

What I usually do is collect the things I want to add in a separate, temporary list and then outside of the loop I call `addAll`.  Here's an example:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Sandbox sandbox = new Sandbox();
        sandbox.devicesList.add("foo");
        sandbox.setVoltage("bar", 1.0);
    }

    private ArrayList<Double> voltagesList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void setVoltage(String device, double voltage) {
        ArrayList<String> newDevicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String d : devicesList) {
            if (d.equals(device)) {
                voltagesList.set(devicesList.indexOf(device), voltage);
            } else {
                voltagesList.add(voltage);
                newDevicesList.add(device);
            }
        }
        devicesList.addAll(newDevicesList);
    }

}
```

Comment: In this case, how can I add to the list?

Comment: Well, you _can_ do that, but only using an explicit `ListIterator` that supports an `add` operation. I will add an answer.

Comment: @Ian one way could be storing the values in temporary `List`s and the using `List#addAll` in your desired lists.

Comment: @Ian but giving a second look at your posted code, seems like you have a design issue. Why are you using two `List`s in parallel instead of using a `List<Device>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
ListIterator<String> iter = devicesList.listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
   String d = iter.next();
   if(d.equals(device)){
       voltagesList.set(devicesList.indexOf(device), voltage);
   }
      else{
         voltagesList.add(voltage);
         iter.add(device);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a collection you're iterating over, unless you're iterating with iterator and calling `iterator.remove()` to modify it.

You can create a new empty collection and add elements to it.